# Convert fasta file (.fasta) to count file (.cf)

Tags: python, converters, fasta

I am trying to convert a fasta file (.fasta) to a count file (.cf) to be able to upload it to IQTREE for use in phylogenetic analysis. The fasta file is a merged file of an alignment and a mapping of the individuals sequenced into one of 5 populations. A sample of this file has been attached.

I have tried both R and python but am not having any success.

Comment: I don't see your attached file. Can you please [edit] to add it?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [PoMo](https://github.com/pomo-dev/PoMo#file-conversion). Specifically, they publish some [scripts for converting files](https://github.com/pomo-dev/cflib)

- [CountsToFasta.py](https://github.com/pomo-dev/cflib/blob/master/scripts/CountsToFasta.py): Convert a counts file to a fasta file.
- [FastaToCounts.py](https://github.com/pomo-dev/cflib/blob/master/scripts/FastaToCounts.py): Convert a fasta file to counts format.
- [FastaToVCF.py](https://github.com/pomo-dev/cflib/blob/master/scripts/FastaToVCF.py): Convert a fasta file to variant call format.
- [FastaVCFToCounts.py](https://github.com/pomo-dev/cflib/blob/master/scripts/FastaVCFToCounts.py): Convert a fasta reference with VCF files to counts format.
- [FilterMSA.py](https://github.com/pomo-dev/cflib/blob/master/scripts/FilterMSA.py): Filter a multiple sequence alignment file (apply standard filters; cf. libPoMo).
- [GPToCounts.py](https://github.com/pomo-dev/cflib/blob/master/scripts/GPToCounts.py): Experimental. Convert gene prediction files with reference to counts format.
- [MSAToCounts.py](https://github.com/pomo-dev/cflib/blob/master/scripts/MSAToCounts.py): Convert multiple sequence alignments with VCF files to counts format.